# How to Find and zip all my pdf files of all subdirectories

Tags: find, zip

I'm trying to find and zip all my pdf files.
find works fine:

> find -iname "*.pdf"

I want to zip everything that is printed into 1 file.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 zip archive.zip
```

That will store everything using its original filesystem path (so e.g. foo/bar/myfile.pdf will be stored in the zip file as foo/bar/myfile.pdf).

Comment: Wow! It worked like magic! You are the BOSS! God bless you, my friend.

Comment: You don't even need `xargs`: `find . -iname '*.pdf' -exec zip archive.zip {} +`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `find` for that.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt extglob
shopt nocaseglob
zip zipfile.zip **/*.pdf
```

(Untested, since typed on my phone)

Comment: It only works on one level unfortunately   ( home/folder/.pdf )
How can it go down to all subdirectories that have pdf files?
Thank you.

Comment: That `**/*.pdf` expression is meant to match multiple levels, but (a) the answer does not enable the correct option (`globstar`), and (b) the answer isn't using the correct syntax for `shopt` (you need `shopt -s <optionname>` to enable an option, so `shopt -s globstar` and `shopt -s nocaseglob`). With those changes this should work.

Comment: Ah @larsks thanks for checking my answer. I'll need to fix it :)